# Any physical or chemical evidence of an RRC 1/1 coin being earlier than 280BCE?

Tags: roman-republic, numismatics

[edited as the question wasn't clear]

Is anyone aware of any physical or chemical evidence of an RRC 1/1 coin being earlier than 280BCE?

Comment: This should help: [How are ancient coins dated?](https://www.cointalk.com/threads/how-are-ancient-coins-dated.326992/)

Comment: @LarsBosteen thank you, but I'm really looking for how those particular coins were dated to around 326 BCE, rather than a general article about dating coins.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking: How do we know that RRC 1/1 coins were struck in 326 BCE *at the earliest*?  Outside my area of expertise, but from what I can see in the literature, these coins were struck in Naples for the Romans. And apparently the earliest possible date is shortly after the conclusion of the treaty between Rome and Naples ("foedus Neapolitanum").

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for the response. I had been thinking that there were some of the coins dated to 326 BCE. Is it that there is no specific coin dated that early, the 326 CE just being guideline as to the earliest date?

Comment: @Glenn I am generally ignorant of numismatics. Please clarify the question you are asking, by editing the question text. Are you asking whether any RRC 1/1 coins have been dated by the use of physical or chemical methods? Or are you asking whether these coins have been assigned a time period based on known historic events that can bracket their age (no earlier than X, nor later than Y) with some, but presumably not complete, certainty?

Comment: @njuffa thanks, sorry for the late reply but have done as you suggested and edited/changed the question to make things clearer.